# Three.js / Collada: this.geometry3js.computeCentroids() undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

When using the ColladaLoader JavaScript throws an "undefined is not a function" error in line 2403 of ColladaLoader.js. Though - i am just loading the .dae like mentioned in the Example:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( './TestCubeCows.dae', function ( collada ) {
});
```

No idea what i am doing wrong!?

I've got a little hint at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6247, though, i guess i am using the newest Version of the Collada Loader?!

Comment: which version of three.js are you using?

Comment: Newest Version. Replaced the Collada-Loader with the JSON-Loader / JSON-Exporter for Blender, and everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the version of collada(the newer version does not have the issue), I went to three.js in github and took the colladaloader from that repo and replaced it in my project.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js